# Doctrine ODM symfony 3: Find by value in a field

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

i want to get an array object of documents where an array fiel contains a specific value.
My collection is something like :

```
{
 "name" : "name",
 "groups" : ["id1","id2"]
}
```

Using doctrine_mongodb and repository, i want for example all the documents where groups field contains value id2.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Actually, i did and  
`$this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:class')->findBy(array('groups' =>
           [$id1]));` worked fine.